# Is my Edubuntu disc AMD64 or i386? (64 or 32 bit)

Tags: iso, edubuntu

I have an Edubuntu DVD. However, I don't know if I burned it using the i386 (32 bit) iso, or the AMD64 (64 bit) iso. Is there anyway to check the DVD file system to see which one it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to check this. One way is to boot the live version using the Try option.

Then check `System Settings` >> `Details` and it will say if it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

To use the DVD file system, mount the DVD in another installation. Check to see if there is an `EFI` folder. That would indicate 64-bit.

You can compare the files in the 32-bit vs the 64-bit versions by comparing the [`.list` files](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04/release/) :

```
edubuntu-14.04-dvd-amd64.list
edubuntu-14.04-dvd-i386.list
```

These are text files that you can open with any text editor; they show you the contents of the DVD that you will see after you have burned the file.

Comment: Thanks for this simple, non complex answer. I will try this soon and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Insert CD/DVD (or `mount -o loop file.iso /mnt`)
The general recommendation is to find 32bit or 64bit specific files without keeping in mind some file names, is to run this `find /mnt/disc -name "*64*"` and run `find /mnt/disc -name "*i386*"`

On the 32bit istallation media you will get:

```
/mnt/1/dists/raring/main/binary-i386
/mnt/1/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386
/mnt/1/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_015-14_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.18.4-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/l/lupin/lupin-support_0.53_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/m/mouseemu/mouseemu_0.16-0ubuntu9_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/s/setserial/setserial_2.17-48_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/w/wvdial/wvdial_1.61-4.1_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/w/wvstreams/libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-6_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/w/wvstreams/libwvstreams4.6-base_4.6.1-6_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/main/w/wvstreams/libwvstreams4.6-extras_4.6.1-6_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
/mnt/1/pool/restricted/s/sl-modem/sl-modem-daemon_2.9.11~20110321-8_i386.deb
```

and on the 64bit installation media you will get this:

```
/mnt/2/boot/grub/x86_64-efi
/mnt/2/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crc64.mod
/mnt/2/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64
/mnt/2/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64
/mnt/2/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
/mnt/2/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
/mnt/2/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/e/efibootmgr/efibootmgr_0.5.4-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/f/fakeroot/libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-efi_2.02~beta2-9_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-efi-amd64_2.02~beta2-9_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-efi-amd64-bin_2.02~beta2-9_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.34+2.02~beta2-9_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/l/lupin/lupin-support_0.55_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/m/mouseemu/mouseemu_0.16-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/s/secureboot-db/secureboot-db_1.1_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/s/setserial/setserial_2.17-48_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/s/shim/shim_0.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/s/shim-signed/shim-signed_1.6+0.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/w/wvdial/wvdial_1.61-4.1_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/w/wvstreams/libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/w/wvstreams/libwvstreams4.6-base_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/main/w/wvstreams/libwvstreams4.6-extras_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb
/mnt/2/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```